# Netbeans v7 C++ debugger bug

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

I have a program that I have written in C++ under linux (Ubuntu 10.10).

The programming and debugging worked perfectly until the moment I added the following lines to the code:

```
mapfile = fopen(map_filename,"wb");
fwrite(map_header,1,20,mapfile);      // <-- this is the problem line
fclose(mapfile);
```

After I added those, the program compiles ok, but the debugger now won't start. It immediately fails with this message:

```
Program completed, Exit code 0x177
error while loading shared libraries: unexpected PLT reloc type 0xcc
```

And if I remove the line with the "fwrite", the debugger will start normally.

This problem only happends inside Netbeans.
When I debug it using the command-line "gdb" it also works ok without any problems.

Anyone have idea why its happening and how to fix it?

P.S: Those problems started recently so I assume maybe it has to do something with system updates, I'm not sure.

Comment: Check it has managed to open the file before you write to it and report the problem if it failed.

Comment: doctorlove, the problem is that the debugger doesn't even start

Comment: I'm not paying enough attention - sorry.

Comment: Are you dynamically linking the shared libraries?

Comment: I am using the Netbeans default configuration.  What do you mean by dynamically linking shared libraries?  where is this option defined?  The output I see from the compiler is: 1. g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp  , and then 2. g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/program build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o

Comment: Perhaps you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in netbeans. Try doing `ldd program` on the command line, to see what libraries your executable depends on. Then make sure all of those libraries' directories are in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting in Project->Properties->Environment.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the cause for this error and also the solution, I'll post this as an answer to my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

Not long ago, I removed some old C++ projects from netbeans. It figures out that netbeans (at least v7.0) remembers all the breakpoints that I put on old projects that don't even exist in the IDE anymore.

I found this by looking at the Debugger Console (Window->Debugging->Debugging Console) and seeing that when "gdb" starts, it tries to setup all these breakpoints from other projects or from projects that do not exists (this is a bug in netbeans, btw)

**The solution:** I simply cleaned all the breakpoints (inside Window->Debugging->Breakpoints) and now the program can be debugged properly.

Hope this will help to anyone out there who has the similar problem.